# Should I assert fail on select() EBADF?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I am trying to fix a bug in a event loop that calls `select()`. When `select()` returns EBADF, an error is logged, then the fd set is re-initialized and select is called again. This results in an infinite hard loop of logging, generating gigabytes of log in a matter of seconds.

This error occurs if one of the tcp servers my program is connected to does an unclean disconnect (eg it segfaults). In this case I would ideally want my program to remove that fd and keep running (or shut down if that isn't feasible).

My question is, should select() ever be returning EBADF, or is that an indication that my program is buggy? I.e. should I assert fail on EBADF, or otherwise, how should I be handling it? Would I loop through the fd set to find the "bad" file descriptor?

Comment: It is a result of sloppy fd administartion. As a *last resort* you could call `fstat()` on all the fds in your fd_sets, and sort them out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a bug in your code. Fix it. Somewhere you are closing a socket without removing it from the FD set used by the selector. Or else you have just made up an FD that isn't an FD and are using it in the FD set.

Contrary to other statements here, network problems cannot cause this error. Network outages do not close sockets, which is the only way they can become invalid. Only closing them does that.  A socket whose connection isn't working will eventually cause an ECONNRESET if you keep writing to it. A socket whose peer has disconnected will become readable and a `recv()` on it will return zero.

Comment: wallyk indicated unplugging a network connection to which a socket is bound might cause this scenario. I'm trying to prove that wrong as well.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart. It doesn't. The socket stays open and you can call `send()` on it without getting EBADF. TCP doesn't magically close sockets from under you.

Comment: I didn't suspect as much, but I wanted to confirm it. Indeed, I used `SO_BINDTODEVICE` to bind a socket to a USB Ethernet adapter, and unplugged it (from the USB port) before calling `select`, which returned successfully.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart VG. Why did you delete your answer? It's quite correct. I voted to un-delete it.

Comment: Others had given the same answer. Regardless, I un-deleted it.

Answer (score 4):

> My question is, should select() ever be returning EBADF, or is that an indication that my program is buggy?

select() returns EBADF if you pass in a descriptor in one of the fd_set's that isn't valid. You shouldn't do that, and it indicates a bug in your program - perhaps you're close()'ing a file descriptor somewhere but didn't remove it from the fd_set.

Comment: Now I'm confused. your answer conflicts with the @wallyk answer. Also I think it is in fact the server that close()'d it and that may be causing the EBADF, not me.

Comment: @grasevski The responsible thing to do would be test that scenario. I don't believe it happens like that.

Comment: @grasevski:  Either network mishaps **or** bad programming could cause this error.

Comment: @wallyk so i CANNOT assume that this is caused by bad programming? that is what I'm trying to establish. Jonathon I will test this when I have time, but given that the bug in question is a nondeterministic concurrency bug I want to make sure my understanding is correct too. I don't want to incorrectly "fix" the bug solely on the basis of a few simple tests.

Comment: i.e. so far i have done some basic testing but it is inconclusive at the moment.

Comment: @graveski It *is* caused by bad programming. Somewhere you closed an FD without removing it from the FD set used by the selector.

Comment: @wallyk Network mishaps cannot cause this problem. A socket whose cable becomes unplugged does not thereby become invalid. Only closing it does that. Such a socket will eventually produce an ECONNRESET If you keep writing to it.

Comment: I just don't see any scenario other than bad programming that causes EBADF to be returned.  As @EJP mentioned in my (now deleted) answer, the server closing the socket definitely makes the socket `read`able. You would have to `close` it for it to become invalid.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I think it would be a good idea to `assert()`.

From the [`select(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) man page:

> **EBADF** An invalid file descriptor was given in one of the sets.
>                 (Perhaps a file descriptor that was already closed, or one on
>                 which an error has occurred.)

This means that you've passed a file descriptor that doesn't actually match a valid open file.

Examples of scenarios that *don't* cause an fd to make `select` fail with `EBADF`:

- A remote socket endpoint closing a connection.  (`recv` returns 0).
- Unplugging a network connection, (or even a USB device).

---

Looking at the Linux kernel source code, we see that `select` can return `EBADF` if it is determined that one of the fds passed in your set does not correspond to an open file in your process. This is checked in [`max_select_fd`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/select.c?v=3.18#L342) in `fs/select.c`

After that check, [`do_select`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/select.c?v=3.18#L399) will only ever return a count of "interesting" fds.  The `file_operations.poll` function for the underlying file is not even capable of making `do_select` return anything different.

It now looks to be **completely** impossible that `select` would return `EBADF` for *any* scenario, other than the programming passing an fd that was either closed, or never open.

Comment: yes, but could this occur for example if the server unexpectedly closed the socket? i.e. is this something I should account for (i.e. handle it rather than assert) or could it only occur if MY program has a bug?

Comment: @grasevski I don't think it can occur if the remote end closes the socket. But I am coding up an example to test this theory.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883282) suspects you didn't `FD_ZERO` your `fd_set`

Comment: If the remote end closes the connection, the local socket becomes readable. It doesn't become invalid.

Comment: VG Now you can get my +1. There is an answer here that should be deleted, but this isn't it.

Comment: NB The Posix *man* page just says 'not a valid file descriptor'.

Comment: I like that explanation much more. The Linux one seems too open-ended, implying that something like what wallyk was saying could happen.

Comment: I suspect the rest of it is just urban myth. 'Perhaps' indeed.

Comment: Very good research. Deserves another upvote, if only I could.

Comment: "Perhaps ... or one on which an error has occurred" - yeah, this is really messing with our minds. Good that we have Linux source code to check that other kinds of errors do not lead to EBADF.